# Update Dataframe Column based on Grouping and Conditionals

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, max

I have three columns which represent my data. I am trying to update the final column 'Val' based on the input of the first two.

I want the maximum of the 'Range', categorised by the 'Cat' column. Following that, I would like to update the 'Val' column based on the minimum value of the 'Val' column in that group.

```
Input
    Cat Range Val
0    1    0   1.0
2    1    2   1.5
3    1    3   2.0
5    1    5   9.0
6    2    0   1.5
7    2    5   2.0
8    2   10   0.5
9    2   15   2.8
10   2   20   9.0 

Desired Output (Only Lines 5 and 10 change):
    Cat Range Val
0    1    0   1.0
2    1    2   1.5
3    1    3   2.0
5    1    5   1.0
6    2    0   1.5
7    2    5   2.0
8    2   10   0.5
9    2   15   2.8
10   2   20   0.5
```

My elementary knowledge of pandas suggested this approach, however it does not work and I cannot seem to resolve it.

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['Cat'])['Range'].max(), 'Val'] = df.groupby('Cat')['Val'].min()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lambda function with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) if need compare by `Val` column:

```
f = lambda x: np.where(x == x.max(), x.min(), x)
df['Val'] = df.groupby(['Cat'])['Val'].transform(f)
print (df)
    Cat  Range  Val
0     1      0  1.0
2     1      2  1.5
3     1      3  2.0
5     1      5  1.0
6     2      0  1.5
7     2      5  2.0
8     2     10  0.5
9     2     15  2.8
10    2     20  0.5
```

Use if need compare by `max` in `Range` column use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) if need replace all max values per groups:

```
m = df['Range'].eq(df.groupby(['Cat'])['Range'].transform('max'))
df.loc[m, 'Val'] = df.groupby('Cat')['Val'].transform('min')

print (df)
    Cat  Range  Val
0     1      0  1.0
2     1      2  1.5
3     1      3  2.0
5     1      5  1.0
6     2      0  1.5
7     2      5  2.0
8     2     10  0.5
9     2     15  2.8
10    2     20  0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to replace only first `max` value of `Range` per group you can use [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) :

```
In [3545]: (df.loc[df.groupby('Cat')['Range'].idxmax(), 'Val'] = 
            df.groupby('Cat')['Val'].transform('min'))

In [3546]: df
Out[3546]: 
    Cat  Range  Val
0     1      0  1.0
2     1      2  1.5
3     1      3  2.0
5     1      5  1.0
6     2      0  1.5
7     2      5  2.0
8     2     10  0.5
9     2     15  2.8
10    2     20  0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.merge(df.groupby(['Cat'])['Range'].max().reset_index(), how='inner').groupby('Cat')['Val'].min()
```

Is this what you're looking for?